# C: parse string into key value pairs

Tags: c, parsing

Is there an easy way to parse a string into k,v pairs?

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1337
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: JSESSIONID.e5614f49=1ns34hepyv53k1hg1o78k3z4zy; screenResolution=1920x1080
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: How do you want the keys and values split? At the first colon?

Comment: first whitespace. I.e. ("Host:","localhost:1337")

Comment: You probably do not need to, and therefore should not, write whatever this is in C.  Write a prototype in a higher-level language - I recommend either Python or Ruby - and then profile it and, *only if it is necessary,* write an accelerator module in C for the most expensive operations.  That will be easier, the result will have fewer bugs, and you will be able to ask much more specific questions about how to do the costly part in C.

Comment: Use the strchr fucntion.

Answer (score 5):

"Easy" depends on how robust and secure you want your code to be.

You can use `strchr()` in a loop, to repeatedly find the spaces and newlines, and `memcpy()` to copy those parts of the string into the structure where you want them.

Or you can use `strtok()` to butcher the string in-place, while collecting pointers into it.

Or you can get more elaborate. Here's a link to the code in Apache HTTPd to do exactly this task: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/server/apreq_parser_header.c